# Synchronize over FTP

Tags: windows, ftp, synchronization

i have to synchronize a folder in a customer computer (Windows Xp) with a server (Windows 2003). The customer has a dynamic IP, so i think do it over ftp. Moreover, the customer computer is down during the night and the amount of data to transfer is about 400Mb, it takes 4-5 hours to upload completely, so i prefer a solution that do incremental updates to save update times/bandwidth.
I've given a try to FTPsync but sometimes has failed.

So, Does somebody give me some advice about some application/solution? Somebody has some experience?

Thanks in advance.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [rsync for Windows](http://www.itefix.no/i2/node/10650), [HERE](http://greenmice.info/en/node/34)'s a guide how to.

Comment: Maybe i'm wrong but i prefer not to install software like rsync/cygwin in a production server that hosts several customers. They look unsafe for me.

Comment: Understood but if you ask most people on this site for an incremental/efficient file transport system most will answer with rsync, which is also available for Windows.

Comment: Ok, i know rsync's advantages, i have several linux environments working with this tool perfectly... but if there is another solution it would be better. Thanks anyway.. if i don't get any better solution i'll give a try to rsync

Comment: Considering FTP is about as unsafe as it gets, switching to rsync over SSH can only make things safer. FTP is an insecure and inefficient protocol that should have been buried years ago when people stopped using Telnet. Remember, it sends all your passwords and files in plain text! OpenSSH is tried and trusted software, Cygwin to allow rsync over SSH is a great solution - don't dismiss it lightly and for incorrect reasons.

Answer (score 0):

You could try xcopy or robocopy.

Comment: It would be perfect, but i think i can't use xcopy or robocopy over ftp. Can I?

Comment: Connect via VPN and you could transfer the files directly from one machine to another. That would also be more secure than FTP.

Answer (score 0):

If you can install cygwin on the machine, try lftp ( http://lftp.yar.ru/ ).

It has a mirror command that may be able to help you.

Plus it can be scripted.

Comment: i would prefer another option like i've said to Chopper3